# Is it okay to use the Id property outside of controllers and models?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**Scenario: online booking system**

Say we have an online booking system which contains a list of customers in a database, and the customer model looks something like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
    public string drivingLicence { get; set; }
}
```

And we want to perform certain operations like:

- search for customers using a unique customer reference number
- search for any bookings a customer has made via a customer reference number
- amend/create a booking by providing the customer's Id in a textbox in a view

Is it appropriate to use the Id property for this purpose? or is it preferred to create a new property for each object like `'CustomerReferenceNo'` and use the Id for querying the database only, keeping the Id property out of the view.

**Example:**

So far I have only been using the Id property to query the database for things like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            // gets the customer details by accessing it's id
            var customerInDb = _context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
```

But was wondering if it's generally common to use it like this:

Note 'Id' is referring to the Customer Id property, to make a booking of a particular customer to a selected hotel.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to user Id only for database purposes. we can't dependent user Id. this user id may be different in different environments.

for e.g.

Customer 'Xyz' is stored in  Dev environment database with id 1.
same Customer 'Xyz' is stored in Test environment database with id 11.
same customer 'Xyz' is stored in Live environment database with id 21.

Its preferable to use customer reference number which is unique across all environments. hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this answer is very helpful. I understand what you are saying about different dev environments, I didn't think of that!